# How to use .dll libraries in Javascript( Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi i am codding a chrome extension. I need to use a library(NZemberek in c#).

Is it possible? How to use it in .js file?

[about: This pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSO2K.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use native code by means of [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

You'd need a separate program that your extension can invoke.

Note that you won't be able to distribute the Native Host through Chrome Web Store, if you're going to publish - you'll need a separate installer.

---

Technically, there's also [NaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client), but that's limited to C / C++ code that *heavily sandboxed*, so you won't be able to normally interact with the system.

Other than that, you can't use native code libraries in your extensions.